# PDF to Excel database

Tags: excel, pdf

I have a PDF document where the data looks like that:

[image: example of one page]

Do you guys maybe know if it is possible to somehow transform that document into an excel database where every information is stacked in a different column? The only way of doing that right now that I can see is just by manually entering it to an excel spreadsheet but maybe there is something that could make my work easier?

Answer (score 0):

It's notoriously difficult to extract structured data from PDF format into Excel.

The best tool I have come across so far is [Tabula](https://github.com/tabulapdf/tabula), which allows you to import data from structured PDF tables.

You may well still need to do some further data manipulation once you have extracted from the PDF file, however.